# How can I run React-router without the jsx transformer

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a really basic app setup where I have the react lib and the router setup as global scripts and it seems that the Router requires the transformer to run. Is there any way that I can get it running without the transformer?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/vendor/react-with-addons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/vendor/JSXTransformer.js"></script> 
<!-- if I remove the transformer then nothing is displayed on the page -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/vendor/ReactRouter.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it seems that this was a user error. I had my main script setup as a jsx file :p

```
<script type="text/jsx" src="/js/dist/app.js"></script>
```

switching to a plain js did the trick!